# References on Integration on non Compact manifolds

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, improper-integrals, change-of-variable

I am looking for references on integration on non-compact Riemannian manifolds, specially on the change of variables theorem.

In particular I have non-compact manifold $M$ and I have an integral (in most interesting cases for me improper integral)

$$\int_M f(x) \mu(dx)$$

Where $\mu$ is standard volume measure on $M$ generated by the metric tensor $g$ on $M$. And I need to make change of variables $y=\phi (x)$, where $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism $\phi: M \to M$. Function $f$ may be unbounded, manifold $M$ may be unbounded (say $M= \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^2$).

I have found reference book only for compact manifolds and bounded functions.

Please help with reference applicable to my case. Thank you very much!

Comment: Amann and Escher's Analysis Volume III might be worthwhile looking at. They develop Lebesgue integration in general, for functions taking values in Banach spaces, and in the integration on manifolds chapter, they make no compactness assumption (besides that forms have compact support for Stokes' theorem). I'm still in the process of reading it so I can't give a very definite review, but hopefully this gives you atleast something to consider.